# Install Python modules for a cluster

Tags: nfs, python, cluster

I've got a small cluster, sharing files by Network File Storage (NFS). We'll be running a lot of Python code, and I'm wondering how best to deal with installing modules. Can I just install them in the shared NFS directory on the head node, and specify the `PYTHONPATH` to there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see anything that will prevent you from using this setup. Just add the folder to the PYTHONPATH from within your bash runcom tree. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196268/where-should-i-put-my-own-python-module-so-that-it-can-be-imported) can be helpful to you – it suggests putting modules in `~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`, but to show the right directory you can use `python -m site --user-site`.

Comment: This seems strongly preferable to installing each module on each node, but I couldn't find anything online about it. Seemed too good to be true!